# ctypes memory management: how and when free the allocated resources?

Tags: python, c, memory, ctypes

I'm writing a small wrapper for a C library in Python with Ctypes, and I don't know if the structures allocated from Python will be automatically freed when they're out of scope.

Example:

```
from ctypes import *
mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary("mylib.so")

class MyPoint(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int), ("y", c_int)]

def foo():
    p = MyPoint()
    #do something with the point

foo()
```

Will that point still be "alive" after foo returns? Do I have to call `clib.free(pointer(p))`? or does ctypes provide a function to free memory allocated for C structures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case your `MyPoint` instance is a Python object allocated on the Python heap, so there should be no need to treat it differently from any other Python object. If, on the other hand, you got the `MyPoint` instance by calling say `allocate_point()` in `mylib.so`, then you would need to free it using whatever function is provided for doing so, e.g. `free_point(p)` in `mylib.so`.

Comment: So I deduce that if some C function called with a pointer to "p" as argument keeps a copy of it somewhere (a global variable, for example), that reference would become invalid after the Python GC claims it, right?